# Arbitrary values for Tailwind CSS Does not work on Blazor WASM Application

Tags: css, blazor, tailwind-css, blazor-webassembly, tailwind-ui

With a Blazor WASM application I'm using Tailwind for UI design, I installed and integrated Tailwind css (V3.3.3) to my project, Every thing works fine except Arbitrary Values !

For example, If I used `class="bg-red"` it works but if I used `class="bg-[#1da1f1]"` it doesn't?

It seems that the problem related to `[]` bracket.

Any help

Comment: Are you compiling sass after changes? `module.exports = {content: ['../Your.Blazor.Project/**/*.{cs,razor}',` ? More info at [using-postcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

Comment: @daniherrera Yes, I did

Comment: How do you build your tailwind? I am using tailwind cli and everything works as expected.